# How to prevent React from re-rendering the whole component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a prop called `isMobile` that displays an external iframe. When I tilt the screen on an iPad, this will change the prop to change values and re-render the iframe (losing all progress inside the iframe).

What is a good way of preventing that re-render? The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) say that I shouldn't use `shouldComponentUpdate`, since that only is a performance optimization.

Comment: Performance optimisation for React is about re-rendering the components or not, so yes use this life cycle method to check your props and re-render or not.

Comment: As the docs say just use the React.PureComponent if `isMobile` never changes then the iframe is never rerendered

Comment: You did not add redux tag, Are you using redux or `setState`?

Comment: @HMR I'm using Redux

Comment: In that case the render function should not be called if you use [connect](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md) and state didn't change. If you set props from parent with something like `path=something.concat(another)` then props will change every render. You should post the part where you pass the props to the component.

Comment: @HMR state does change, though

Answer (score 5):

As some answers said, you can use a `React.PureComponent` that it avoid to re-render with any reason to do it, so you can fix it, separating your `Iframe` into a single component with the `React.PureComponent` so it would be like this:

```
class MyPureIframe extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const {src, width, height} = this.props;
    return (
      <iframe src={src} width={width} height={height} {...whateverProps} />
    );
  }
}

class MyNormalView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <!--SOME MARKUP HERE-->
       <MyPureIframe src={'https://your-url-to-iframe'} width={100} height={100} />
       <!--SOME MARKUP HERE-->
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So the `MyPureIframe` only will change (re-render) when some of its props change (src, width, height, or other that you passed down).

In that way no matters in the `MyNormalView` re-render the deep component `MyPureIframe` won't re-render until any of its props changed.

I hope it can help you.

### Updated May 2020

Because the answer above is related for class based component, if you use a functional component, it mean a function that render some html markup, you can still use this approach as follow.

```
import React, {memo} from 'react';

const MyPureIframe = memo(({src, width, height}) => (
  <iframe src={src} width={width} height={height} {...whateverProps}/>
));

class MyNormalView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <!--SOME MARKUP HERE-->
       <MyPureIframe src={'https://your-url-to-iframe'} width={100} height={100} />
       <!--SOME MARKUP HERE-->
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Doing like so, you will get the same result, but using a functional component instead.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: For TypeScript happiness (though that wasn't a tag here, so I'm not adding an answer): `const MyPureIframe = memo( ( props: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.IframeHTMLAttributes<HTMLIFrameElement>, HTMLIFrameElement>) => <iframe src={props.src} />);` [eslint might also require a `displayName`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61229562/1028230): `MyPureIframe.displayName = 'MyPureIFrame';`

Answer (score 0):

shouldComponentUpdate is not a better approach. The document says it can ignore the changes to shouldComponentUpdate in future.
Please try using the concept called `memoize` which is better than PureComponent

Comment: Can you provide some code to explain that concept? That would be useful information for people to read in your answer.