# React eslint error：Component definition is missing display name

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

Using `Reac.memo` to wrap my functional component, and it can run smoothly, but the eslint always reminded me two errors:

```
error    Component definition is missing display name  react/display-name

error    'time' is missing in props validation         react/prop-types
```

Here is my code:

```
type Data = {
  time: number;
};
const Child: React.FC<Data> = React.memo(({ time }) => {
  console.log('child render...');
  const newTime: string = useMemo(() => {
    return changeTime(time);
  }, [time]);

  return (
    <>
      <p>Time is {newTime}</p>
      {/* <p>Random is: {children}</p> */}
    </>
  );
});
```

My whole code:

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';

const Father = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const [random, setRandom] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setTime(new Date().getTime())}>
        getCurrTime
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setRandom(Math.random())}>
        getCurrRandom
      </button>
      <Child time={time} />
    </>
  );
};

function changeTime(time: number): string {
  console.log('changeTime excuted...');
  return new Date(time).toISOString();
}

type Data = {
  time: number;
};
const Child: React.FC<Data> = React.memo(({ time }) => {
  console.log('child render...');
  const newTime: string = useMemo(() => {
    return changeTime(time);
  }, [time]);

  return (
    <>
      <p>Time is {newTime}</p>
      {/* <p>Random is: {children}</p> */}
    </>
  );
});

export default Father;
```

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992932/component-definition-is-missing-display-name-react-display-name answer your question?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's because you have eslint config which requries you to add displayName and propTypes

Do something like

```js
const Child: React.FC<Data> = React.memo(({ time }) => {
  console.log('child render...');
  const newTime: string = useMemo(() => {
    return changeTime(time);
  }, [time]);

  return (
    <>
      <p>Time is {newTime}</p>
      {/* <p>Random is: {children}</p> */}
    </>
  );
});

Child.propTypes = {
  time: PropTypes.isRequired
}

Child.displayName = 'Child';
```

Comment: Wondering if someone can explain why this only happens when using memo?

Comment: There is a probably a plugin somewhere in your build-pipeline that generates the displayName for react components based on the variable name that the react component is stored in. In the case of React.memo the react component is not stored directly in a variable, but instead is an anonymous function inside the React.memo call. Therefore the displayName cannot be inferred.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with React and TypeScript, you can turn off the `react/prop-types` rule.

This is because TypeScript interfaces/props are good enough to replace React's prop types.

Comment: Typescript and PropTypes serve different purposes. Typescript validates types at compile-time, whereas PropTypes are checked at runtime.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Yep, you are right. My main intention was for the OP to turn off that rule since they do not seem to be using prop-types. I agree my answer was poorly worded.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial the problem with that is it can be extremely difficult to make PropTypes work with TypeScript, as the type definitions between the two are challenging to keep in sync. IMO, PropTypes messages in the browser console get ignored far too much, I would rather have strong compile time TypeScript props than the weak runtime checking that PropTypes offers.